# Is there a continuous-time stochastic process that, when sampled, yields discrete-time Gaussian white noise?

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

Is there a continuous-time stochastic process that, when sampled perfectly, yields discrete-time Gaussian white noise? I want both *Gaussian* **and** *white* because I know that there can be no continuous-time stochastic process that satisfies both.

I suppose that one can construct artificial examples if the sampling rate is pre-specified, so I should ask if there is a continuous-time stochastic process that yields Gaussian white noise for *any* sampling rate.

Comment: It would be helpful here if you define your terms and provide some motivation. I suspect that you implicitly want your stochastic processes to have path regularity, which will cause issues. If you don't care about path regularity, then Kolmogorov's extension theorem probably implies the existence of what you want.

Comment: @chris-janjigian: Thank you for the reminder of that theorem. I wanted to know if discrete-time Gaussian white noise, ubiquitous as a model of noise in digital signal processing, could arise from sampling a continuous-time stochastic process. I'm not hoping for a physically realistic process. I know the model was introduced for simplicity, but I wonder if it can be justified at any level other than "it has worked well so far".

Comment: Ok, then the answer is "yes" that such a process exists. For what it's worth, I think that isn't the right question though. The "right" definition of a continuous-time Gaussian white noise is a mean zero random tempered distribution with covariance given by a Dirac delta. The discrete Gaussian space-time white noise process that you are interested in arises by sampling an average of the true continuous-time white noise process over some region of space. Physically, this averaging has to be there because no measurement could ever even in principle go down to arbitrarily small scales.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian: Thank you for your insight.